# Get Data from Cloud Custodian into an Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudcustodian

I want to export data from Cloud Custodian to an  Amazon S3 bucket. I understand Cloud Custodian can be easily integrated with AWS Security Hub and once I have data in security hub using event bridge i can dumb it to an  Amazon S3 bucket but in my use case I don't have flexibility of integrating to cloud custodian to AWS Security Hub.

What are the alternative approaches if I directly want to export data from Cloud Custodian to an Amazon S3 bucket ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an s3 bucket as the output directory of your Cloud Custodian run

```
custodian run --output-dir s3://SOME_S3_BUCKET CLOUD_CUSTODIAN_POLICY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command, `custodian report -s s3://uri`